# Java EE migration Weblogic to Glassfih Jersey

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish, weblogic, jax-rs

I am trying to migrate Weblogic to `Glassfish` but there is a problem with `webservices` libs. The log which is belong to Glassfish's shown below;

> java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.util.ServiceConfigurationError:
>   javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer: Provider
>   weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer
>   not found

I think the app uses weblogic specific libs. Is the any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GlassFish comes with its own Jersey e.g. org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.init.JerseyServletContainerInitializer so you need to find out where in your app the WebLogic provider for JAX-RS is specified and remove that. Starts with your beans.xml if you have one and any jaxrs  in your web.xml

Comment: I could not find anything about  weblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer , is there any config file etc. ?

Comment: I suggested to check beans.xml and web.xml - did you check those?

Comment: beans.xml is empty and there is nothing aboutweblogic.jaxrs.server.portable.servlet.JerseyServletContainerInitializer in the web.xml.

Comment: it could be anything weblogic - nothing comes up if you grep weblogic in your project?